# Node.js error when making a request with superagent

Tags: node.js, superagent

it is my code

```
const superagent = require("superagent");

superagent.get("https://www.baidu.com");
```

When running the script, it prints out into console:

`superagent: Enable experimental feature http2`

What should I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

The message in the console is not an error, it is a warning from the library, as supposedly, you are using the latest version `v4.0.0-beta.2`.

Support of `http2` was added to superagent just [recently](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/pull/1399) and was not released yet.

You can ignore the message, after verifying that requests are successfully made.

If it bothers you too much, it is possible to downgrade to the latest release version - [v3.8.3](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases/tag/v3.8.3). Which does not have a warning.

Comment: yes,very thanks,when i downgrade to 3.8.3,it works prefect!

Comment: 0.21.0 i want this version not sure how to downgrad keep getting 3.8.6